# Issues with nodejs' request and pipe

Tags: node.js

I'm having an issue with the following code. I'm trying to make a POST request (json) to a URL using pipe but I get the error "write after end" - Internal Server Error. Can someone please help?

```
test: function( req, res, next) {
 var requesty = request.post({
            url: dataUrl,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        });
        req.pipe(requesty).on('error', function (error) {
            logger.withRequestLog(res, 'error', 'CC Melville Proxy failed!', {
                assetUrl: dataUrl,
                error: error,
            });
            next(error);
        }).pipe(res);
}
```

Comment: is req and res coming from express? And what is request? is it request library?

Comment: request is the request library and req and res are coming from express

Comment: I edited the post to make it easier to understand. Check it again. I'm using the request library to pipe.

Comment: The usual form is `readable.pipe(writable)`.   Can you describe in WORDS (in your question) what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to make a post request to a URL and then pipe the response body.

Comment: Please put that description IN your question.  Also, how do you expect to stream to a POST request when you are already specifying the `body` option.  You can't send both a body and stream to the POST.

Comment: Why are you doing `req.pipe(requesty)`?  What are you expecting to accomplish with that?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of `body: JSON.stringify(body)`. You can't (also don't need) to pass body as when you are piping raw bytes are being piped as well. Also This middleware should be FIRST as you don't want to use `bodyParser` etc which will read the stream and make it empty.

Below is an working example where I am proxying my request to one my routes(It can be external also):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const request = require('request');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser').json();
const dataUrl = '/employees'

app.use(dataUrl, bodyParser, (req, res)=>{
  res.json({
    body: req.body || {},
    method: req.method,
    param: req.params,
    headers: req.headers,
    url: req.url
  });
})
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  var requesty = request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080'+dataUrl,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  })
  req.pipe(requesty).on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('error', 'CC Melville Proxy failed!', {
      assetUrl: dataUrl,
      error: error,
    });
  }).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('started');
})
```

**Note:** You don't need to specify method as it will automatically be passed. From the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming):

> You can also pipe() from http.ServerRequest instances, as well as to
>   http.ServerResponse instances. The HTTP method, headers, and
>   entity-body data will be sent.

Comment: Hi dataUrl is on another domain. I'm trying to access an external API

Comment: Yeah this is just an example. You can use any urls external or inernal.